# Sending the wrong Params on a nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having issues with the implementation of a nested form for a model with has_many through relationship

I have 3 models: Reservation, Table and Collection (Join Model for these two)

In my Reservation Controller I have these two methods:

```
  def new
    @reservation = Reservation.new
    @tables = Tables.all
    @tables.size.times {@reservation.collections.build}
  end
```

and

```
def reservation_params
  params.require(:reservation).permit(:name, collections_attributes: [ :table_id, :units_sold],
          tables_attributes: [:units, :title])
end
```

my form view is as following:

```
    <%= form_for [current_user, @reservation] do |f| %>

<header>
    <h1>Make Reservation</h1>
</header>

    <%= f.text_field :name,         placeholder: "Name" %>

    <%= f.fields_for :collections  do |builder| %>
        <%= render 'nested_form', :f => builder %>
    <% end %>

    <%= f.submit "Save" %>     

<% end %>
```

and my _nested_form.html.erb file:

```
<%= f.number_field :units_sold,     placeholder: "Units" %>
<%= check_box_tag  :table_id %>
```

My problem is, whenever I save a new entry on the database he assigns the same table_id to all collections association, e.g:

I want to receive the Parameters hash such as:

```
 "collections_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"units_sold"=>"5", "table_id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"units_sold"=>"6", "table_id"=>"2"}}}
```

Instead what I'm getting is:

```
"collections_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"units_sold"=>"5", "table_id"=>"1"}, "1"=>{"units_sold"=>"6", "table_id"=>"1"}}}
```

How do I fix this for it to give the correct table_id for each collection?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you provide your models' snippet that shows their associations.

Anyway, according to your form; One Reservation has many tables through collections.

change:

```
<%= check_box_tag  :table_id %>
```

to

```
<% @tables.each do |table| %>
  <li>
    <%= f.radio_button :table_id %>
    <%= f.label :table_id, table.name %>
  </li>
<% end %>
```

By this, you will be able to choose one table from all for each collection using radio button.

Hope this will help!